# cURL error on OpenIndiana: "error: error setting certificate verify locations"

Tags: curl, openindiana

I was trying to `git clone` a repository using `https://` on OpenIndiana, and got the following error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gak/vagrant/.git/
error: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/curl/curlCA
  CApath: none

warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution on http://zero-knowledge.org/post/78:

```
mkdir /etc/curl && cat /etc/certs/CA/*.pem > /etc/curl/curlCA
```